# Change iPhone tableview (style grouped) background color while preserving texture

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can we change the background color of tableview (style grouped) while still preserving texture of thin columns/lines effect that we can see when it has the default blue color.If i try to change background color using backgroundcolor property i get a plain view without any texture.

thanks

Answer (score 75):

```
tableview.backgroundView = nil;
tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This may help you in solving your problem

Comment: Worked for me too, but I set the backGroundColor to the color I wanted instead of making it `clearColor`

Comment: @Ali Yes you can set the background color as per your requirements.tableview.backgroundView = nil will help you to remove the plain view from the grouped table.

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, you could try searching on Stack overflow for your exact question. Here's two:

- [How can I set the background of a
  UITableView...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894875/how-can-i-set-the-background-of-uitableview-the-tableview-style-is-grouped-to-u)
- [How to customize the
  background/border colors of a grouped
  table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)

If that doesn't help, try to make the background colour of the table view transparent `[UIColor clearColor]` and put another view behind your UITableview containing the colout/texture/image you need.

Comment: Making the background color transparent will result in bad performance, methinks.

Comment: depends what you're after. It will but it might not kill your app.

Comment: Once I set the cell background color to clear it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Create the property of tableView:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Then synthesize it:

```
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
```

In implementation create method:

```
- (UITableView *) tableView {
  [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  return _tableView;
}
```

Remember also to connect your tableView in xib file, and it should work.

Comment: This is bad practice, you're much better off doing this customisation in viewDidLoad (it's confusing and your UI calls will be repeated each time table is accessed)

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to write code, simply select *Clear Color* for the table view's *Background* property **in the *View*  section**.