# how to change the background colour in UITableViewStyleGrouped in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the background colour of a cell inside UITableView from default white to something else. If the style is UITableViewStylePlain then its very easy and we can just do:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However, the same is not happening inside UITableViewStyleGrouped.

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this post!
[#933992](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933808/change-iphone-tableview-style-grouped-background-color-while-preserving-texture/933992#933992)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change iPhone tableview (style grouped) background color while preserving texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933808/change-iphone-tableview-style-grouped-background-color-while-preserving-texture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we can do is use an UIImageView that will span the whole of the cell. Couldn't find a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

When using UITableViewStylePlain, tableView do not have a backgroundView, but when it comes to  UITableViewStyleGrouped, we can see tableView's backgroundView is not nil.
So the solution is simple, set this backgroundView to nil, and it's done.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

And you can see the blackColor background now!

Answer (score 3):

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];
```

try this and you can change cell background color.