# Change background on a UITableView embedded in a UIViewController on iOS 5

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to change the grey gradient background on an embedded UITableView to the color I have set on the parent view in the Storyboard.

I have been looking around, and found the following threads:

- [Change iPhone tableview (style grouped) background color while preserving texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933808/change-iphone-tableview-style-grouped-background-color-while-preserving-textur)
- [How can I set the background of UITableView (the tableview style is “Grouped”) to use an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894875/how-can-i-set-the-background-of-uitableview-the-tableview-style-is-grouped-t)
- [UITableView backgroundColor always gray on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688007/uitableview-backgroundcolor-always-gray-on-ipad)

I have an IBOutlet in the parent controller connecting the two views.

My implementation looks as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activeShipmentsTable setBackgroundView:nil];
    [activeShipmentsTable setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [activeShipmentsTable setBackgroundColor:UIColor.clearColor];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting et the background color on the table's background view, not the table itself.

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = view;
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work! I also found out that it does not matter wether the code snippet is inserted into loadView or viewDidLoad. Do you know what best pratice is?

Comment: I, personally use -loadView only for creating the main view. Any other subviews get added in -viewDidLoad and get removed in -viewDidUnload.