# How to remove rounded corner background on UITableView group style when cell is selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using a UITableView with group style. I made some specific changes and the normal view of the cell no longer has the rounded corners on grouping. I would like to remove this and just use the plain style of selection. I tried setting `selectedBackgroundView` to `nil` for the cell returned by `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`, but it doesn't change anything. Is there something else I must set to get this behavior?

As a side note, I do have to use group style and I know its weird that I basically want it to act like a plain style table on selection, but there are certain behaviors inherent to group style tables that I wanted, just not the look.

Comment: What behaviors of a grouped table do you want that are not present in a plain UITableView??

Comment: Due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047979/ios-uitableviews-moving-header-of-a-section-off-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting selectedBackgroundView to nil, I actually added an actual UIView. This seems to work in replacing it. Now I just need to find out how to make it look like the plain one, but this has at least solved my initial problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**then use**

```
CALayer * layer = [table layer];
        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer setCornerRadius:0.0]; //note that when radius is 0, the border is a rectangle
        [layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
        [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Where am I adding this? Do you want me to create a class that inherits from UITableViewCell and add this to drawRect?