# Xcode 4.2 UITableViewCell background

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

What is now the proper way to set the background image for normal and selected states of UITableViewCell? In XCode 4 I used to do it in the IB but now these options are not available.

Comment: Does this help? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894875/how-can-i-set-the-background-of-uitableview-the-tableview-style-is-grouped-to

Comment: It talks about the uitableview - not the cell. I was wondering about the recent change in xcode that there is no place to choose the background image in the IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting the cell.backgroundView:

```
            UIView *backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background.png"]];
            cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

For the selected state I used the default blue selection.

Comment: Yes. paste it in if (cell == nil)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"image_name" ofType:@"png"]];

UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];

cell.backgroundView = av;
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?