# backside of a window after scrollable place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

there is an iphone background image backside of my application. I can see it when i try to scroll a scrollable view too much. you can see it on the photo. Are there any way to change it with another iphone default backgrounds or a custom image?

Thx,

[image: Default iphone background of a window]

Edit: I'm not asking for background color and clearColor of a view. This is something like my applications background or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers could help

- [How can I set the background of a
  UITableView...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894875/how-can-i-set-the-background-of-uitableview-the-tableview-style-is-grouped-to-u)
- [How to customize the
  background colors of a grouped
  table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)